Xcode C++ how to read file inside xcframework and pass it to sqlite load_extension?
I have an xcframework bundled in my app. Inside this xcframework there is a framework file that contains a sqlite dylib I want to get the path for and then load it into sqlite.
I've managed to get a path into the file by doing:
NSString *resourcePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];
NSString *crsqlitePath = [resourcePath
      stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Frameworks/crsqlite.framework/crsqlite"];

This gives on the simulator:
/Users/osp/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/2542B85E-15F0-4262-92A8-C20FC7C9908A/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/EDF0FBCE-FCAA-466D-89D5-FE197FF41B1D/OPSQLiteExample.app/Frameworks/crsqlite.framework/crsqlite

Then when after I create a sqlite db I try to load it:
char* errMsg;
const char* crsqliteEntryPoint = "sqlite3_crsqlite_init";

sqlite3_load_extension(db, crsqlitePath.c_str(), crsqliteEntryPoint, &errMsg);

I then get the error:
not authorized

So I'm guessing that iOS is not happy accessing the file inside the framework so willy nilly. Is there anyway I can give access to this file or maybe copying it to the documents folder is the only way?

Found the issue. It has nothing to do with iOS permissions. I had to execute sqlite3_enable_load_extension(db, 1); before loading the extension.
Also found another way of getting the path to the framework file path that is a bit more robust:
  NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleWithIdentifier:@"io.vlcn.crsqlite"];
  NSString *crsqlitePath = [bundle pathForResource:@"crsqlite" ofType:@""];


I think you may have issues getting your app onto the App Store. I recently had a project that used a .dylib in an app extension and it was rejected during submission with an obscure ITMS-90427 error.  This was solved by embedding the .dylib in a .framework, but I doubt that would work for you.

don't think so, there are other libraries that already embed cr-sqlite and everything seems to be fine
